# Command clear won't take kill signal ( in infinite loop | c program )

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I used the command "clear" in C language at infinite loop just for test and the kill signal does not stop it.

Why the program does not stop when i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    while (1) {
        system("clear");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `system` is already declared in the `stdlib.h`, so why did you declare it?

Comment: thank you for info. i will remove from question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing `clear` will not help, because the infinite loop is in your own program.  Kill *that*.

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> is only useful if you can get the system to pay attention.  It sounds as if your terminal is too busy writing to the screen to do this.

From *another* terminal, run `top` and kill your program (which likely is near the top of the screen).

Answer (score 1):

You could include a signal handler to 'catch' your CRTL-C input (which is SIGINT below) and then exit.  Hopefully, this stub code will give you the idea.  If not, I can provide a complete working example but would like to see you try first.  :-)

```
#include <signal.h> 

...
void stop (int signal) { 
  exit; 
}

int main() {
  signal(SIGINT, stop); 
...
}
```

HTH

Comment: yw.  Glad I could be of assistance.  Could I get an upvote on my idea?   :-)

Comment: i need 15 reputation :/ when i get to 15, i will upvote :)

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  Best wishes. Thx.